# Covariance of m-fold integrated Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

**The problem**

I'm trying to perform a Bayesian approach to the Maximum Likelihood Estimation procedure of [Wecker and Ansley (1983)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2287113). To this end, I need to compute the full likelihood of the data given the model, which after some algebra turns out to have a covariance matrix whose elements are given by:

$$\Sigma_{j,k}=\mathbb{E}[Z^{m}(x_j)Z^{m}(x_k)]+\delta_{j,k}\sigma^2,$$

with $\delta_{j,k}$ the Kronecker delta and where

$$Z^{m}(x_i) = \lambda^{1/2}\sigma \int_{x_1}^{x_i}\frac{(x_i-h)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}dW(h),$$

and $\lambda^{1/2},\sigma$ are constants and $W(h)$ is a Wiener process with unit dispersion parameter. Here is where I'm stuck (I'm fairly new to stochastic calculus): I need to obtain this expected value. The authors say this matrix should be of the form $\Sigma = \sigma^2\Lambda$, where the $\Lambda$ matrix depends only on $\lambda$, but I need the full functional form of the $\Sigma$ matrix in order to write the full likelihood!

**What I have tried**

The whole problem is to obtain

$$\mathbb{E}[Z^{m}(x_j)Z^{m}(x_k)]=\lambda \sigma^2 \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{x_1}^{x_j}\frac{(x_j-h)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}dW(h)\int_{x_1}^{x_k}\frac{(x_k-h)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}dW(h)\right],$$

and I know, by Ito's isometry that, for $s<t$:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^s f(u,W(u))dW(u) \int_0^{t}g(v,W(v))dW(v)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^s f(t,W(t))g(t,W(t))dt\right],$$

so, can I say (note the lower integration limit) that, for $x_1<x_j<x_k$,

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{x_1}^{x_j}\frac{(x_j-h)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}dW(h)\int_{x_1}^{x_k}\frac{(x_k-h')^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}dW(h')\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{x_1}^{x_j}\frac{(x_j-t)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\frac{(x_k-t)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}dt\right]?$$
Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to use Itô's isometry ?

Comment: @TheBridge yes, but, how do you handle the different integration limits?

Comment: (I edited my answer to reflect my question)

Comment: I think you are almost done but first there must be typo on the bounds of the integral and second you don't need expectation operator now because everything is deterministic. Best regards

Comment: Thank you very much; I think now is ok...isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In full generality, for deterministic functions $B$ and $C$, and for $a\leqslant b$, $a\leqslant c$, $$E\left(\int_a^bB(h)\mathrm dW(h)\cdot\int_a^cC(h)\mathrm dW(h)\right)=\int_a^{\min\{b,c\}}B(h)C(h)\mathrm dh.$$

Comment: Awesome, then the result I posted is good; thanks!